# is it possible to show alerts instead of woocommerce error messages

Tags: error-handling, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to show alerts on cart page instead of regular error messages, like show "Coupon doesnot Exist" message as `alert("Coupon doesnot Exist")` instead of regular woocommerce messages.. Is there is any way to do that? Thanks for help